# PHP: How to combine INSERT with UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

My project is a simple attendance record for my small school. I am submitting entry and exit logs through an online form, and writing them to a database with this query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_one (first_name, last_name, location)
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$location')";
```

It works fine - so far so good.

At the same moment I would like to write some of this submitted information to another table in the same database. This query works fine by itself when standing alone:

```
$sql = "UPDATE another_table SET location='$location' WHERE first_name='$first_name'";
```

However my problem is how to make them both happen, in sequence. Just listing them successively doesn't work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_one (first_name, last_name, location) VALUES 
('$first_name', '$last_name', '$location')";

$sql = "UPDATE personnel_table SET location='$location' WHERE 
first_name='$first_name'";
```

What is the most effective (and safest) way to combine both commands so that they execute together?

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE another_table SET location='$location' WHERE first_name='$first_name'";` here you should be using that person's userID as an identifier otherwise if your table have `John` and you add another `john` this will update all `John` s records

Comment: *"Just listing them successively doesn't work"* -- why it doesn't work?

Comment: Here you are just writing a string named $sql

Comment: All insert queries give you the inserted row's id, like $mysqli->insert_id (return last inserted id)

Comment: 1. Simply assigning those strings to a variable isn't what does the query. [Notice here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm) the call to `mysql_query()`. You must run each one successively. 2. I strongly recommend that you [do not interpolate](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) into those SQL query strings. 3. I strongly recommend that you do not write SQL yourself in PHP. There's loads and loads of frameworks and ORMs to do that for you so much better than hand-written queries.

Comment: @erapert Please, **DO NOT** link to tutorials that use `mysql_query`. That thing has done so much harm to the PHP community that they've removed it from PHP as of version 7. Any tutorial that references it is wickedly out of date at best, and potentially dangerous. Your other advice can stand on its own. There's no reason to recommend to people to use that `mysql_query` junk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use transaction so that if one query fail, both should fail. Only if both query success that it will add/update the database.

```
$db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $sh = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_one (first_name, last_name, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $sh->execute([$first_name, $last_name, $location]);

    $sh = $db->prepare("UPDATE personnel_table SET location=? WHERE first_name=?");
    $sh->execute([$location, $first_name]);

    $db->commit();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this problem you must use trigger option in database (forEx mysql).

trigger is like an event. when insert in on table automate update second table. forEx:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE account (acct_num INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
       FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

this trigger that is a object for account table. update @sum variable and then use for update second table

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger like below:

```
delimiter # 
create trigger after_ins_trig after insert on first_table
 for each row begin
UPDATE second_table 
SET new.location=old.location 
WHERE new.first_name=old.first_name end#
delimiter ;
```

You can check id in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
Table: teraz
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `teraz` (
  `col` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

//

```
<?php 
$last_name = 77;
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','shopping');
$sql = "INSERT INTO teraz VALUES ('{$last_name}')";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM teraz";
$conn->query($sql);
$result = $conn->query($sql2);
$x = $result->fetch_assoc() ;
echo $x['col'];
?>
```

?

Comment: If you're using `mysqli` you absolutely must be using prepared statements with placeholder values. It's also a bad plan to use `latin1` here, `utf8mb4` is a significantly better default, though specifying it here is redundant since there's no character columns.